# show that $d_p$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $p$ be prime.

For an integer $ a \neq 0$ we define:

$ v_p(a) = \max$ { $ n \in \mathbb{N} | p^n $ divides $a$ }

Consider for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$: $$ d_p(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
p^{-v_p(x-y)} & x \neq y \\
0 & x=y \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

Now I have to show that $d_p$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Z}$.

attempt/question:

the first property $ d(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$ holds by definition. Here is nothing to show. We can only mention that $p^{-v_p(x-y)}$ is never $0$.

the second property $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ holds because if $n$ is the $\max n$, so that $p^n$ divides $x-y$, then $p^n$ divides  $y-x = (-1)(x-y)$. the sign doesn't change the fact that this is our $\max n$ here.

but I'm stuck regarding the third property. I mean I have to show that:
$d_p(x,z) \leq d_p(x,y) + d_p(y,z) $. I have consider different cases. the three cases $x=y $, $ x=z$ and $y=z$ were easy. But what can I say about $ x \neq y \neq z $. Here I have to show $p^{-v_p(x-z)} \leq  p^{-v_p(x-y)} +  p^{-v_p(y-z)} $. I don't find a good reasoning here.

Comment: if $p^n|x-y$ and $p^n|y-z$, then $p^n|x-z$; if $p^n|x-y$ and $p^m|y-z$, then $p^{\min(m,n)}|x-z$

Comment: this is the [$p$-adic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order)

Comment: Im sorry, that I didn't see that this question already exists. Thank you for your help. I get it now.